# how to use contains in dict in swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, contains

I wrote a func to merge two dicts, where the second dict covers the first dict where they share same keys

```
 func merging(_ dict1: [String: String],with dict2: [String: String]) ->
[String: String]{      
    var toreturn : [String : String] = dict1      
    for (key,value) in dict2{    
        toreturn[key] = value
    }   
    return toreturn}
```

it works with all my test cases, then I failed to wrote a "dumber" version of it with the contains method:

```
func merging(_ dict1: [String: String],with dict2: [String: String]) ->
[String: String]{
    var toreturn : [String : String] = dict2
    for (key,value) in dict1{
        if(toreturn.contains(where: [key, value]))
    }
    return toreturn}
```

Can anyone help me with rewriting the func with the contains method?

Comment: "I wrote a func to merge two dicts, where the second dict covers the first dict where they share same keys" Why reinvent the wheel? That's built in: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary Look for the four `merge` and `merging` methods.

Comment: What do you want to do in your second function?

Comment: @matt, the `merge()` and `merging()` methods were added in Swift 4/Xcode 9.0, correct?

Comment: Sorry for being not clear, I was going through a practice book and the book asked me to redo the method without looking at the API.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a new function to merge to Dictionaries in Swift , as per [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2919576-merging) you only need to use Dicitionary merging method example :

```
let dict1 : [String: String] = ["a" : "1" , "b" : "2"]
let dict2 : [String: String] = ["c" : "3" , "d" : "4"]

let newDict = dict1.merging(dict2) { (current, _) -> String in
    current
}

//newDict values will be : ["a" : "1", "b" : "2", "c" : "3", "d" : "4"]
```

Comment: Sorry for being not clear, I was going through a practice book and the book asked me to redo the method without looking at the API.